# How to filter gmail based on html

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is there any way to filter gmail based on html? In particular, I get tons of political spam from people who have signed up using my email address. It is always from ngpvan and there is always an unsubscribe link that refers to "email.ngpvan.com", but it doesn't seem to register in a plain search. Any trick for doing this?

Comment: I had the same question and based on what I've seen in my searching, it does not appear that Gmail allows you to search on content in the HTML source of your email; only the text visible to you in normal reading mode. I've also tried searching for `ngpvan`, `actionnetwork`, `forwardblue`, and `emaildeputy`, all of which are TLDs used in unsubscribe URLs for political solicitations I received, to no avail. 